# Deleting the last blank line when pasting an Excel sheet into a text file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to paste data from an Excel sheet into a text file but when I do this there is one last blank line in the text file that I want to delete without having to go into the file and do it manually. My code and what I mean about the text file are include below.

```
Sub Ref_to_text()

Dim s As String, FileName As String, FileNum As Integer
 
  ' Define full pathname of TXT file
  FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("REF Hydro 1").Range("H1").Value & ".txt"
 
  ' Copy range to the clipboard
  Range("A1:B362", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy
 
  ' Copy column content to the 's' variable via clipboard
  With New DataObject
     .GetFromClipboard
     s = .GetText
  End With
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 
  ' Write s to TXT file
  FileNum = FreeFile
  If Len(Dir(FileName)) > 0 Then Kill FileName
  Open FileName For Binary Access Write As FileNum
  Put FileNum, , s
  Close FileNum

End Sub
```

Blank space I want removed

[image: Blank space I want removed]

What I want file to look like

[image: What I want file to look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the last vbcrlf

```
With New DataObject
     .GetFromClipboard
     s = .GetText
     s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 2) ' Add this line
  End With
```